# datatables asp.net core razor pages IActionResult new JsonResult

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, datatables

How I can set the table content on selection change I am talking about datatables.js library, via jquery ajax post. How I can return new JsonResult and redraw the table's content with the result from the handler ? Thanks

Comment: Hi CCTV, you are much more likely to get an answer if you provide some code for what you have already tried. It is rather difficult for users to answer questions when they are not able to see the code you are working with. Please edit to show the code you are working with and explain what you have already tried :)

Comment: I understand that it is a conceptual question, but providing information about what you have tried and example code, even if it is wrong, gives people a place to start when attempting to answer your question. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also, I was not attempting to answer your question but provide you with advice so you can get a great answer to your question. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the process I use:
Summary:

1. Declare a js variable at a top level scope
2. In the document.ready function, instantiate the data table to your global js variable
3. On ajax post clear the table via the stored object and then iterate the results and add the rows

More in depth:

```
//declare this high in scope so you can access it in your functions
var dt;

$(document).ready(function () {
   //Create the datatable and assign it to variable for later reference
   dt = $('#MyTable').DataTable({dom: 'Bfrtip'});
});

$("#SomeBtn").click(function () {
  //clear current table rows
  dt.clear().draw();
  $.ajax({
         url: whatever Path,
         data: whatever Data,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, n) {
                    //Iterate results and add each to the table. This is why we stored the datatable in a highr scope so we can operate it on it here :)
                    dt.row.add([n.prop1, n.prop2, n.prop3]).node().id = n.propID + '_Row';
                    dt.draw(false);

                });
            },
            error: function (response) {
            },
            failure: function (response) {

            }
        });
 });
```

As you can see, by storing the datatable in an object when you instatiate it, you can control it in later functions per its api

Comment: What would be the correct json format for consumption by the datatable whould you show simple json example please? P.S. your answer is of great help so far.

Comment: There is not a "correct" format. That said you can make it easier on yourself by returning simple view models in your Json Result. So server side, when you return your JsonResult, it is just going to convert you ViewModel/View to json then client side it is converting your json automatically to a js object. What you are seeing in my example is a a return type of List<myClass> whereas myClass has properties of prop1, prop2, prop3 as strings and propID as int. Honestly, the easiest thing to do is to do a console.log(data) on the ajax result, open dev tools and see the js object created.

Comment: If you returned a single instead of a list then you could just as easily access your data via data.prop1 and data.prop2. The trick with js objects though is you will need to handle things like null values or datetime formats because it won't do it for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've got it sorted out with your help. Here is simple example for the response:  return new JsonResult("[[\"Tiger Nixon\", \"System Architect\", \"Edinburgh\", \"5421\", \"2011/04/25\", \"$320,800\" ], [\"Garrett Winters\", \"Accountant\", \"Tokyo\", \"8422\", \"2011/07/25\", \"$170,750\"]]");